# myProcess.Start() file not found

Tags: vb.net

создал 2 проекта vb.net...

первый консольное приложение

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        While True
            Console.WriteLine("test")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End While
    End Sub

End Module
```

собрал.

затем второе с гуи, из которого хочу запустить первое

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        startTmp()
    End Sub


    Private Sub startTmp()
        ' обмен данными с внешним процессом через 
        ' функции StdIn, StdOut и StdErr
        Dim myProcess As Process = New Process()
        ' описание и запуск процесса
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "с:\console_test.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ""
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        myProcess.Start()
    End Sub

End Class
```

выдает ошибку на строке myProcess.Start() о том что файл не найден. Файл 100% есть и путь с названием 100% верные.

IDE - VS comunity 2017

Что не так?

Comment: У меня Ваш код работает. Попробуйте запустить с соммандной строки файл (скопируйте адрес), чтоб еще раз убедиться в правильности адреса.

Comment: сейчас немного разобрался, проблема не в имени и не в пути, проблема в том что при `myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False` файлы запускаются из директорий прописанных в системной переменной PATH или из той же директории откуда вызывается, но указать конкретный путь в этом случае через параметр `WorkingDirectory` нельзя согласно документации. Остается вопрос как указать абсолютный путь.

Comment: @koshe исходя из этой документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx я понял что либо добавлять путь консольного приложения в PATH либо держать его в той же директории где приложение которое его запускает, иначе ошибка file not found. Все же надеюсь что есть способ это победить...